# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) when launching app from .ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using a PDF reporting library, named PDFReporter, and I've got this weird crash when trying to generate a PDF. **It happens only when I'm launching the app from an .ipa archive**. It runs fine when I launch the app from Xcode.

Here's some of the trace I have from Xcode's Device logs :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010 
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog: None found

Thread 0 name:  main  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181501b90 objc_msgSend + 16 
1   ExpoTouch                       0x0000000100649e64 OrgOssPdfreporterEngineXmlJRXmlDigesterFactory_setComponentsInternalEntityResourcesWithOrgOssPdfreporterEngineXmlJRXmlDigester_
    + 72 
2   ExpoTouch                       0x000000010064a054 OrgOssPdfreporterEngineXmlJRXmlDigesterFactory_createDigester + 136 
3   ExpoTouch                       0x00000001006849d4 OrgOssPdfreporterEngineXmlJRXmlLoader_load__WithJavaIoInputStream_ + 140
4   ExpoTouch                       0x000000010071062c +[ReportExporter loadReport:] + 72
```

So the question is : what's the difference between installing from Xcode and installing from an .ipa ? Am I missing a library in the .ipa ? If so, how could I know which one ?

Comment: It looks more like a memory management problem.  "objc_msgSend" is most commonly seen on top of the stack when a message is sent to a released object.  (Sometimes when a message is sent to the wrong kind of object.)  If I was going to point at Xcode/non-Xcode differences, I might start with code optimization settings.

Comment: Thank you, that's indeed what it seems like. I must admit I'm pretty clueless about code optimization settings in Xcode, where would you look in particular ? Linker flags maybe ? Bitcode ? Are there online resources that might be helpful ?

Comment: Well, I changed the "Optimization level" from "Fastest, Smallest" to "Fast", and that did the trick ! Thank you so much. If you write a proper answer I'll accept it. Cheers !

Comment: If it helps anybody, [here are the differences between optimization levels](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH9-SW2).

Comment: I was guessing about optimization.  :)  It's very probable that there's something still basically wrong in the program, but subtle enough that it's only seen under selected conditions.  However, without knowing what the code at frame #1 of your trace is doing, I can't tell you what the bug might be.

Comment: This crash happens 4 layers deep into the PDF reporting library. I don't have the time to dig it up and debug it, so that'll be good enough for now ;)

Comment: Good question. I'm facing the same issue but changing Optimization Level didn't solve my problem. I have another workstation installing Xcode. Somehow, I managed to make it worked by generating the .ipa in that machine. I guess, in my case that was the problem of provisioning profile but cannot figure out why as I was using the same PP file for both machines.